# Error compiling source file and header file together in C++

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, header-files

This is not actual code i am working on but sample code i had written to understand what i am doing wrong. So i have three files ***main.cpp***, ***favourite.cpp*** and ***favourite.h***. I am trying to compile main.cpp but get some weird error.

**// main.cpp File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "favourite.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    favNum(12);

}
```

**// favourite.cpp File**

```
#include "favourite.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void favNum(int num)
{
    cout << "My Favourate number is " << num << endl;
}
```

**// favourite.h File**

```
#ifndef FAVOURITE_H
#define FAVOURITE_H

void favNum(int num);

#endif
```

This all files are in same folder and i am compiling it normally like **g++ main.cpp** I am not sure if i need to compile it diffrently as i am using custom header files.

Comment: @ZanLynx i got the answer it was problem with linker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say `g++ main.cpp` and this is your whole command line, the error is a linker error that it can't find `favNum`, right? In that case, try:

```
g++ main.cpp favourite.cpp
```

or split compilation and linking:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c favourite.cpp -o favourite.o
g++ main.o favourite.o
```

Where `-c` means: Compile only, no linking and `-o`*`filename`* is required because you want to write the output to two different object files to link them with the last command.

You might also add additional flag, the most important ones are:

```
-Wall -Wextra -O3
```

Comment: ok i got this and one more question I have included iostream in both my files. Does that make any problem.

Comment: @Nakib `iostream` won't make any problem. You want to add include guards to your header, though. It's not required yet for the simple example you just posted, but soon enough you will need them, so just make it a habit that all headers should have include guards.

Comment: i had edited the code can u check if it is correct. I mean the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I guess I see the error although you should have included it in your question.

When compiling multiple source files you need to list them all on the GCC command line. Or you can use a Makefile.

So you could do this:

```
g++ favourite.cpp main.cpp
```

Or you could write a Makefile like this:

```
all: program
program: main.o favourite.o
```

And then just type:

```
make
```

Comment: I think that Makefile needs a bit more explanation, as it invokes some "magic" by not listing the .cpp files at all.

Comment: @hyde: Well, there is GNU Make documentation or there are questions and answers here on Stack Overflow.